# Setting customer headers in CURL using php doesn't work

Tags: php, rest, curl, custom-headers

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init (); 
$headers = array ( 
    "Content-Type: application/json", 
    "ulogin : abc",           
    "Authorization : abcdefgh"
); 
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/api/orders/209");
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

$result = curl_exec ( $curl );

if ($result === false) {
   die ( 'Error fetching data: ' . curl_error ( $curl ) );
} else {
   var_dump ( $result );
}
curl_close ( $result );

?>
```

The url is a java rest api service. This GET request when received on the service end shows all the header values null.
I tested the service with postman with headers set and it goes through.
Not sure what am i missing in the php code.

code snippet from my service:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String token = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        String userEmail = httpRequest.getHeader("ulogin");
}
```

**UPDATE**
   I tested with postman, and a sample java client. Both works. Only from php it is not working.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/api/order/165");
      request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      request.addHeader("ulogin", "abc");         r 
      request.addHeader("Authorization", "abcdefg");
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      System.out.println( response.getHeaders("Authorization"));

     }
```

**UPDATE2**

Using get_file_contents also works

```
  $url = "http://localhost:8080/api/order/165";

  $options = array(
 'http'=>array(
 'method'=>"GET",
 'header'=>"Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
          "ulogin: abc\r\n" .     
          "Authorization:abcdefg\r\n"       
  )
  );

  $context = stream_context_create($options);
  $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  var_dump($file);
```

Comment: try without the space after the header name - there should be one before the value however

Comment: Thanks it worked! I am not able to upvote your comment as i dont have enough reputation. But I spent the last few hours trying to figure out this issue. Glad you replied!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if you want include headers, there is an option

```
CURLOPT_HEADER  TRUE to include the header in the output.
```

[Php.net CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with how you set the headers in php.

When you call a php script that shows the headers it was requested with it shows the 3 headers you have set. Paste the following code in a new php file and call that with your current code. You will see it works great.

```
var_dump(getallheaders());
```

One small note in curl_close you neet to add the curl handler not your parsed result. Change the following line

```
curl_close ( $result );
```

To

```
curl_close( $curl );
```

Comment: I pasted your code in test.php and called that in my curl url.  
I am not sure why it is coming as null in my service code.

curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/api/test.php"); 
" HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2015 07:35:34 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 195 Content-Type: text/html REQUEST **************
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
ulogin: abc
Authorization: abcdefgh

Comment: @user5118993 I don't know why your java code doesn't recognize the headers. Sadly my knowledge of java is extremely poor so i can't help you there.

Comment: Java client and PHP client using get_file_contents seem to work. somethign is wrong about setting the headers with curl.